# How to design a Flutter screen with gradient background

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[image]

I'm currently working on a Flutter project and I'm trying to design a screen with a gradient background. I'm relatively new to Flutter and I'm having trouble implementing the gradient background. I've tried a few approaches, but none seem to be working as expected.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: I want the screen to have a gradient background that smoothly transitions from one color to another. Additionally, I need to overlay some widgets on top of this gradient background.

Could someone please provide me with guidance or sample code on how to achieve this?

Comment: Share some code that you have tried doing and then you can get help. for starter, you can try gradient of color from transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using a Stack widget in Flutter to overlay text on an image. The image is fetched from the network and is set to fit the height of the container. I've applied a linear gradient on the image to create a fade effect from transparent to black towards the bottom. The text is positioned to start after 30% of the height from the top of the screen. Here's the code snippet:

```html
Stack(
  children: [
// Container that fills the screen height
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, // Set the height to the full screen height
  foregroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
    // Apply a linear gradient to fade from transparent to black
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      stops: [0, 0.3], // Stops for the gradient, indicating start and end points
      colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.black], // Colors used in the gradient
      begin: Alignment.topCenter, // Start the gradient from the top
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter, // End the gradient towards the bottom
    ),
  ),
  // Network image that fills the container's height
  child: Image.network(
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1632299768491-51d27b80d088?q=80&w=2591&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D',
    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight, // Make the image fit the height of the container
  ),
),
// Container for the text that appears on top of the image
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), // Add some padding around the text
  // Position the container to start after 30% of the screen height from the top
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3),
  // Text widget for displaying the string 'Lets You In'
  child: Text(
    'Lets You In',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), // Set text color to white
  ),
)
  ],
)
```

Try using this code for the below output[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]How about an Container with child and foreground decoration starting from the bottom? Please change the CupertinoColor or CupertinoIcons to Color or Icons if you use Material instead of Cupertino theme.

```
          Container(
            foregroundDecoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  CupertinoColors.black,
                  Color(0x00000000), // transparent color
                ],
                begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                end: Alignment.topCenter,
                stops: [0, 1],
              ),
            ),
            child: Image.network(
              loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                  ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                return const Center(
                  child: Text("Loading ..."),
                );
              },
              "https://www.ephotozine.com/articles/71-amazing-examples-of-landscape-photography--26838/images/xlg_lrg_185834_1400173414.jpg",
              errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception,
                  StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                    return const Icon(
                        CupertinoIcons.nosign,
                        size: 30,
                       color: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
                    );
              },),
          ),
```